# ¿Como modifico la url de redireccionamiento al restablecer una contraseña? en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

No ubico cual es el archivo que contiene el redireccionamiento al restablecer exitosamente la contraseña.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la ruta `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;` dentro de `ResetPasswordController` se tendría que modificar la variable `redirectTo` a la ruta que desea redirigir después de hacer el reset de contraseña.

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/urlaredirigir';
```

> Cabe destacar que es necesario que esta ruta exista en `routes.php`

Comment: Lo extraño es que esa variable no estaba en ese controlador, por ende creí que allí no sucedía eso, veo tu respuesta y agrego la variable y ahí sirvió. Bueno simple ignorancia. Gracias hermano de nuevo :D

Comment: @PabloContreras la variable sí estaba para mi  , Laravel 5.4. Igual estamos para ayudarnos, Saludos.

Comment: Igual Laravel 5.4